# add image icons to a combo box in java

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jcombobox, imageicon

i`m trying to add image to JComboBox in java in netbeans. i checked all properties  and i couldn't find any property to add icon.
also i checked the solution in google , also there is no solution for it.in proper way.the code all interfaces in codings and it seems very not userfrendly.
using this http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/CustomComboBoxwithImage.htm

so how can i come-up with this question?

Comment: Start by having a look at [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) and [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html). The answer is, you're going to have to get your hands dirty, get out the form editor and write some code

Comment: actually a want to create a combobox like change availabilty.items like available,offline like that...

Answer (score 2):

> i`m trying to add image to JComboBox in java in netbeans

You can't add an Image directly to the combo box but you can add an ImageIcon to the combo box.

[The default renderer for the JComboBox supports Icons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer).